# MobileVLCKit Playing video streaming not displays

Tags: ios, objective-c, vlc

I have implemented  `MobileVLCKit` in iOS  by using MobileVLCKit framework. I have an issue,

When I declare the player @Interface the streaming and voice is working well.

```
#import <MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.h> 
 @interface ViewController ()<VLCMediaPlayerDelegate>{
        VLCMediaPlayer *vlcPlayer1
  }
    @end
```

But, declare the VLCMediaPlayer object at local function the video preview not displayed but, audio id playing.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   VLCMediaPlayer *vlcPlayer1 = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithOptions:nil];
   vlcPlayer1.drawable = view;
   media = [VLCMedia mediaWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: UrlString]];
  [vlcPlayer1 setMedia:media];
  [vlcPlayer1 play];
}
```

How can I resolve the issue. Because, I need to create the view dynamically.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[vlcplayer.media addOptions:@{ @"network-caching" : @300}];
```

If it doesn't work, replace 300 with a bigger value.
That may work.

Answer (score 0):

So both of these questions/answers put me on the right path, but this is ultimately what worked for me.

```
NSURL* _uri    = [NSURL URLWithString:uri];
NSArray* initOptions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"--codec=avcodec", "--network-caching=10000", nil];

self.player = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithOptions:initOptions];
self.player.media = [VLCMedia mediaWithURL:_uri];
```

It looks like the "addOptions" is valid, but my particular use case wasn't picking it up, and instead I had to actually initialize the VLCMediaPlayer with the options from the get go. Worked out nice because it actually fits much better with other JAVA/Android/CMD line VLC api's.